# Bottom navigation bar buttons don't work flutter

Tags: flutter

I used for my flutter app this package https://pub.dev/packages/google_nav_bar and when i tried to add onPressed function to my buttons to redirect to a new UI it didn't work. It's like i just click and nothing happens , this is what i added to the example code from the package

```
  GButton(
                            icon: Icons.favorite,
                            text: 'Saved',
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (_) => FavoriteProviders()));
                            },
                          ),
  GButton(
                    icon: Icons.send,
                    text: 'Messages',
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (_) => MessageList()));
                    },
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                }),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin [Presistant_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar).now i can use bottomnavbar on every screen
also with 15+ style bottomnavbar variants

```
PersistentTabController _controller =PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

//Screens for each nav items.import Class your Views
  List<Widget> _NavScreens() {
    return [
     FavoriteProviders(),
     MessageList(),
     Container(color: Colors.green);
     Container(color: Colors.red);
     Container(color: Colors.yellow);
      
    ];
  }


  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
       icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        title: ("Saved"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        title: ("Messages"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
        title: ("Help"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity),
        title: ("ProfileScreen"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity),
        title: ("Demo"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),

    ];
  }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PersistentTabView(
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _NavScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9,
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: i have updated the answer,let me know it if work for you,if not update the question with tried code @sanda17

Comment: I wanted when you touch to be redirected to the new UI not to open the Ui inside the other UI

Comment: I don't understand..@sanda17

Comment: I don't understand..what you mean by " redirected to the new UI not to open the Ui inside the other UI" @sanda17

Comment: I want the buttons to open a new UI not to keep my first UI in the background

Comment: i had this same  code works with multiple app,in this case in when i press `Saved` bottombar icon it will got to ` FavoriteProviders(),` this view,if i press i press second icon it will goto  MessageList(), it act as sepreate view not single one, try remove `FavoriteProviders and MessageList ` from the list then add a container with other color check if it show correct container  when you press in each bottombar icon.@sanda17

Comment: if it shows correct container then it might  be problem with your views,also if didn't show the container update the tried code @sanda17

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/soWbkZp i want this Favorites UI to be open as a page , not just like this

Comment: i don't want the action from the List<Widget> _NavScreens()  to happen , i just want the buttons to redirect to a new page , it is possible?

Comment: I want just to use the onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FavoriteProviders()));
          }

Comment: it's the same thing,i this bottombar you can just import the class name just like Navigator push,it's the same thing@sanda17

Comment: `mgur.com/a/soWbkZp i want this Favorites UI to be open as a page , not just like this`,is the appbar with name and two icon,is it part of favorite page or you might want check the view you showing,the bottombar works fine as you can see in the image,but the appbar is fixed i think,please look into the appbar@sanda17